# load language files during build in Vite JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte, vite

I am making a webapp using ViteJs and svelte (not sveltekit).
in this project i need to have multiple languages. and to do that i am using JSON files as dictionaries. the problem is, i want to give the ability to the Admins to modify the translations and text from their page.

what i need is a way to load these JSON files from a back-end server when building, through a GET request. instead of doing it on runtime (for performance reasons). is there anyway to do that ?
thank you very much

Comment: How do you intend to get the modified translations back to the server?

Comment: that process is done on another webapp, that is a lot more basic and is disconnected from the main pages